# Cannot delete folder as superuser

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, permissions, shell

There is a folder structure on a external harddrive created by some software a couple years ago that looks like this

```
b7960f2d3fccff0ddb9dc9cb471b562d/xbox360/*unknown*
```

I'm unable to delete the folder using the Windows Explorer, getting a standard permission denied error.
Using the Windows Ubuntu shell, I got the following information (I gave myself ownership):

```
d--x--x--x 1 (my shell user) (my shell user) 512 Apr  5  2018 xbox360
```

even though I made myself owner, I can not delete the folder (not even as sudo) give myself writing permission and I can not read lsattr:

```
lsattr: Permission denied While reading flags on ./xbox360
chmod 777 xbox360/
d--x--x--x 1 (my shell user) (my shell user) 512 Apr  5  2018 xbox360
```

I also cant access the folder structure beyond xbox360, getting the following error:

```
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
```

I'm at my wits end. Why can't I delete/change permissions on this folder as sudo and as the owner? And how do I get rid of this folder?

E: The folder is also not mounted

E2:

```
D:\>dir /x b7960f*

 Verzeichnis von D:\

21.03.2021  15:56    <DIR>          B7960F~1     b7960f2d3fccff0ddb9dc9cb471b562d
               0 Datei(en),              0 Bytes
               1 Verzeichnis(se), 820 872 986 624 Bytes frei

D:\>del /s /q B7960F~1
D:\>dir

21.03.2021  15:56    <DIR>          b7960f2d3fccff0ddb9dc9cb471b562d
```

E3:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way:

- Run CMD as Administrator
- Use the `cd` command to navigate to the parent folder
- Use the command `dir /x b7960f*`
- The name will also be displayed in a short form similar to `b7960f~1`
- Run the command `del /s /q b7960f~1` to delete the folder and all its contents.

Comment: that sadly had no effect (I edited my post with the commands and console output)

Comment: Could you please right-click the folder, select Properties, click Security tab, click Advanced button, and add a screenshot.

Comment: I added a screenshot. Please let me know if you need a translation of anything.

Comment: Translation: "You do not have permission to view the security properties of this object even though you have administrative rights. Click on "Andern" at the top to take ownership of the object (includes permission to display its properties)".

Comment: Click on "Andern" to take ownership. That will most likely solve your problem.

Comment: yes that worked, thank you